# anorm dynamic filters

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0, anorm

I'm studying a little the anorm documentation (from play framework) and is not clear if it supports a common query use case: dynamic filters, that is the user fills in 2 or 3 search criteria on a 10 fields search form.

In this case how can I dynamically construct the query without the classic string manipulation?

Comment: It looks to me like there is an answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15591479/dynamic-sql-parameters-with-anorm-and-scala-play-framework), but I don't understand what `whereString` is supposed to be, so I don't fully understand that question.

Comment: Also, similarly, what about dynamic "order by" lists?

Comment: @Robin Green So the whereString would be something like what I posted below:
    `({countryCode} is null or c.code = {countryCode})
 and ({capital} is null or c.capital = {capital})`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes, I think the question referenced by Robin Green contains the answer. Just define your query with all the possible criteria using placeholders (e.g. `{criterion1}`) and call the `on()` method on the query, passing the actual `Seq` of `Option` parameters as described in the accepted answer.

---

Modified example from the Anorm doc, assuming you have two criteria but only want your query to filter on the country code and not on the capital:

```
SQL(
"""
select * from Country c 
join CountryLanguage l on l.CountryCode = c.Code 
where ({countryCode} is null or c.code = {countryCode})
  and ({capital} is null or c.capital = {capital});
"""
).on("countryCode" -> Some("FRA"), "capital" -> None)
```

That should do the trick.

Comment: This is nice, but seems to have limitations with some more "exotic" types like ZonedDateTime or LocalDateTime (from java.time) even if those types otherwise work very nicely with Anorm. Trying to use this with optional ZonedDateTime, I got "ERROR: could not determine data type of parameter $1". If anyone wants to give it a shot, try applying this approach to [my use case](http://stackoverflow.com/q/34078955/56285).

Comment: @Jonik Didn't try it, but maybe that would work if you pass `Option.empty[ZonedDateTime]` instead of `None`?

Comment: Thing is, it always fails at runtime (with "could not determine data type of parameter") whether the optional ZonedDateTime is present or not (no matter if it is `Some(2016-01-09T17:19:25Z[UTC])` or `None` or `Option.empty[ZonedDateTime]`). I have a [complete test case at GitHub](https://github.com/jonikarppinen/play-testbench/commit/debaf5fda4ff31604b533de64940a8fb5267b25a#diff-f9416156fa807ad43ab0ac4606d87b5bR68) if you want to have a look.

Comment: @Jonik That seems to be an [issue](http://www.postgresql.org/message-id/Pine.BSO.4.63.0608292151450.28706@leary2.csoft.net) with the Postgresql driver.
It's really ugly, but probably that if you used `{created}::timestamptz` instead of `{created}` it would work.

Comment: Thanks, with `({created}::timestamptz is null or created >= {created})` it indeed works fine!

Answer (score 3):

Short answer first. Suppose say you have a table in database containing 3 columns: `name`, `email`, `pass`. But from the user, you only got `name` and `password` but not `email`. So make Options of all 3

```
val name:Option[String] = Some("alice")
val email:Option[String] = None
val pass:Option[String] = Some("password")

//For db insertion have this:

  DB.withConnection { implicit conn =>
  SQL("INSERT INTO USERS (name,email,pass) VALUES ({n},{e},{p})").on(
 'n -> name, 'e -> email,'p -> pass).executeInsert()
 }
```

Doing the above, as `email` is `None`, it will insert `null` in your database. So in your case, for all your 10 columns, you can define them in the `SQL` statement above and pass `Option` in `on()`. If any of them is `None`, then it will take it as `null` in database.

Though there can be a issue if there is a constraint on a column in your schema as `NOT NULL`. In which case you can use `getOrElse` for such columns asbelow:

```
DB.withConnection { implicit conn =>
  SQL("INSERT INTO USERS (name,email,pass) VALUES ({n},{e},{p})").on(
 'n -> name, 'e -> email.getOrElse("Default Email"),'p -> pass).executeInsert()
```

The below is a comprehend list on how play converts the type to database type. It can be found in object `anorm.ToStatement`:

```
        case Some(bd: java.math.BigDecimal) => stmt.setBigDecimal(index, bd)
        case Some(o) => stmt.setObject(index, o)
        case None => stmt.setObject(index, null)
        case bd: java.math.BigDecimal => stmt.setBigDecimal(index, bd)
        case date: java.util.Date => stmt.setTimestamp(index, new java.sql.Timestamp(date.getTime()))
        case o => stmt.setObject(index, o)
```

Above you see, for `None` it takes it as null.

---

In case of `SELECT` hmm, I am not aware of any anorm feature which helps here, but I guess simple String manipulation might suffice:

```
def getColumns(xs:List[Option[_]]):String = {
    val notNone = xs.collect{
       case Some(x) => x.toString
    }
    notNone.mkString(",")
}
```

And then `SQL("SELECT %s from table".format(getColumns(List(nameColumn,emailColumn,passColumn)))`.

Though this is not what you want. Anorm is just a sql building library. To do what you want, it will also have to remember your table schema (i.e. atleast column names..). I do not think anorm is made to do all that

Comment: This question is about a search (i.e. a SELECT query) not an insertion. Maybe I'm missing something but I can't see how it would work for a SELECT.

Comment: @RobinGreen Hmm then I do not know of anorm feature which does that. Anyways edited it.

Answer (score 0):

Anorm seems to cleary operate on the premise that you insert plain old SQL, without any features such as typesafety or query building. It probably isn't the right tool for dynamic queries. Constructing queries has to be string manipulation eventually, so I would recommend using a library that does this for you. It should be easy to integrate any library for generating SQL statements with Anorm.

You can dynamically construct a query and pass that query string to Anorm with a library like [jOOQ](http://www.jooq.org/). As a bonus you'll get support for many databases. jOOQ seems to be popular but there probably are many other libraries that you could use instead. Or replace Anorm completely if it isn't suited for your project.